# Drupal 7 View context filters with the URL (when used in a panel)

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels, uri

I am currently trying to get my view to display in a panel under certain contexts. Specifically, I want the view to take the end of my URL and use that as a key to find the taxonomy term that corresponds with it and then display the product information I have stored on a separate product datasheet.

For example, if I have a hypothetical taxonomy animals -> mammals -> cats (where cats has a panel page), and a URL example.com/mammals/cats, I want to take cats off the end of that URL use it as my term for the context filter, find the corresponding datasheet with that name, then pull the relevant information.

I can get the datasheet information to display fine, as well as get the right pages, if I input cat into the test filter on the view edit page. However, When I try to use it in a panel, I can not figure out how to get Drupal to take "cat" from the URL for use in the filter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been working on this for a day using a bunch of different solutions with no success.